# Custom div that acts as a radio button

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I'm working on a website and am having troubles implementing a div (has product name, price & image) that behaves like a radio button (something like this https://www.harrys.com/en/us/signup/products)

Any type of solution would be appreciated, I'm currently using bootstrap4 & JQuery/Javascript

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted...

Comment: Neither do I...don't you wanna save my rep and put it back on 0 :P

Comment: Ticked it up a notch for ya :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to let the user click the label for the radio button. This allows for the div surrounding it to do something else and appear to be what you are actually clicking. You must also use the "for" attribute in the label to reference the id within the input.

Radio will deselect the others and select the one that has been clicked if you use the name attribute. notice on the markup that all radios contain the name "myradio". Although they have different id's.  This is so you can pull back this data and use it to your liking.

Notice the CSS does the heavy lifting. We let it look for an input that has been checked (input[name="myradio"]:checked) and use the "+" to grab the next element after it (.clickable or .clickable .checked-box).

I've also added a little jQuery to the example to show the id of the selected box in the console so you can see what I mean for data return.

Also here is a link for more info on the CSS selector I used.

CSS element+element selector

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Sample</title>
        <style>
            .div-inline-list{
                margin: 24px auto;
                width: 80%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .div-inline-list > .product-container{
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 16px;
            }
            .product-container{
                position: relative;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .product{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

            }
            .clickable{
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                border: 1px solid green;
                border-radius: 4px;
                transition: all ease .5s;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            .checked-box{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                width: 22px;
                height: 22px;
                background-color: #0055ff;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                display: none;
            }

            input[name="myradio"]:checked + .clickable{
                border-color: #0055ff; 
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #0055ff;
            }

            input[name="myradio"]:checked + .clickable .checked-box{
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- create the div inline boxes -->
        <div class="div-inline-list">
            <!-- create the product container the user sees -->
            <div class="product-container">
                <input id="prod1" type="radio" name="myradio">
                <label for="prod1" class="clickable"><span class="checked-box">&#10004;</span></label>
                <p class="product">Prod 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
                <input id="prod2" type="radio" name="myradio">
                <label for="prod2" class="clickable"><span class="checked-box">&#10004;</span></label>
                <p class="product">Prod 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
                <input id="prod3" type="radio" name="myradio">
                <label for="prod3" class="clickable"><span class="checked-box">&#10004;</span></label>
                <p class="product">Prod 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Added jquery since you are using bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //on radio button "myradio" state change log to the console to view
                $('input[name="myradio"]').change(function(){
                    console.log("#" + $('input[name="myradio"]:checked').attr('id'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is it chief

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use a class to indicate which button is selected, then trap each button click and:

(1) Turn the class off on all buttons,

(2) Turn the class on for the clicked button

Simple, elegant, works.

```js
$('.myradio').click(function(){
  $('.myradio').removeClass('myactive');
  $(this).addClass('myactive');
});
```

```css
.myradio{display:inline-block;}
.myactive{background:dodgerblue;color:white;}

/* Appearance only */
.myradio{padding:3px 7px;margin-left:10px;border:1px solid dodgerblue;border-radius:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myradio myactive">One</div>
<div class="myradio">Two</div>
<div class="myradio">Three</div>
```

If you want, you can also give each div a unique ID, and keep track of which ID has the "active" class. That allows you to identify which button is currently selected and perhaps send that data somewhere.